# org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Bad Request Bad Request request: http://localhost:8080/solr/update?wt=javabin&version=2

Tags: java, solr, hadoop

Please help me guys
I am trying to crawl the sites using NUTCH, But it gives me error "`java.io.IOException: Job failed!`"

I am running this command "`bin/nutch solrindex http://<host name>:8080/solr/ crawl/crawldb -linkdb crawl/linkdb crawl/segments/*`" and i am using NUTCH 1.5.1 and SOLR 3.6.1 and jdk java-7-openjdk-i386 and ubuntu 12.04.

In hadoop.log exist within NUTCH/log folder displays the following things:

```
2012-09-13 12:56:10,524 INFO  solr.SolrIndexer - SolrIndexer: starting at 2012-09-13 12:56:10

2012-09-13 12:56:10,604 INFO  indexer.IndexerMapReduce - IndexerMapReduce: crawldb: crawl/crawldb

2012-09-13 12:56:10,604 INFO  indexer.IndexerMapReduce - IndexerMapReduce: linkdb: crawl/linkdb

2012-09-13 12:56:10,604 INFO  indexer.IndexerMapReduce - IndexerMapReduces: adding segment: crawl/segments/20120910160403

2012-09-13 12:56:10,711 INFO  indexer.IndexerMapReduce - IndexerMapReduces: adding segment: crawl/segments/20120910160448

2012-09-13 12:56:10,715 INFO  indexer.IndexerMapReduce - IndexerMapReduces: adding segment: crawl/segments/20120910160631

2012-09-13 12:56:10,760 WARN  util.NativeCodeLoader - Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable

2012-09-13 12:56:11,212 INFO  plugin.PluginRepository - Plugins: looking in: /home/zapbuild/Nutch/plugins

2012-09-13 12:56:11,310 INFO  plugin.PluginRepository - Plugin Auto-activation mode: [true]

2012-09-13 12:56:11,310 INFO  plugin.PluginRepository - Registered Plugins:

2012-09-13 12:56:11,310 INFO  plugin.PluginRepository -     the nutch core extension points (nutch-extensionpoints)

2012-09-13 12:56:11,310 INFO  plugin.PluginRepository -     Regex URL Normalizer (urlnormalizer-regex)

2012-09-13 12:56:11,310 INFO  plugin.PluginRepository -     CyberNeko HTML Parser (lib-nekohtml)

2012-09-13 12:56:11,310 INFO  plugin.PluginRepository -     OPIC Scoring Plug-in (scoring-opic)

2012-09-13 12:56:11,310 INFO  plugin.PluginRepository -     Basic URL Normalizer (urlnormalizer-basic)

2012-09-13 12:56:11,310 INFO  plugin.PluginRepository -     Tika Parser Plug-in (parse-tika)

2012-09-13 12:56:11,311 INFO  plugin.PluginRepository -     Basic Indexing Filter (index-basic)

2012-09-13 12:56:11,311 INFO  plugin.PluginRepository -     Html Parse Plug-in (parse-html)

2012-09-13 12:56:11,311 INFO  plugin.PluginRepository -     Anchor Indexing Filter (index-anchor)

2012-09-13 12:56:11,311 INFO  plugin.PluginRepository -     HTTP Framework (lib-http)

2012-09-13 12:56:11,311 INFO  plugin.PluginRepository -     Regex URL Filter (urlfilter-regex)

2012-09-13 12:56:11,311 INFO  plugin.PluginRepository -     Regex URL Filter Framework (lib-regex-filter)

2012-09-13 12:56:11,311 INFO  plugin.PluginRepository -     Pass-through URL Normalizer (urlnormalizer-pass)

2012-09-13 12:56:11,311 INFO  plugin.PluginRepository -     Http Protocol Plug-in (protocol-http)

2012-09-13 12:56:11,311 INFO  plugin.PluginRepository - Registered Extension-Points:

2012-09-13 12:56:11,311 INFO  plugin.PluginRepository -     Nutch URL Normalizer (org.apache.nutch.net.URLNormalizer)

2012-09-13 12:56:11,311 INFO  plugin.PluginRepository -     Nutch Protocol (org.apache.nutch.protocol.Protocol)

2012-09-13 12:56:11,311 INFO  plugin.PluginRepository -     Nutch Segment Merge Filter (org.apache.nutch.segment.SegmentMergeFilter)

2012-09-13 12:56:11,311 INFO  plugin.PluginRepository -     Nutch URL Filter (org.apache.nutch.net.URLFilter)

2012-09-13 12:56:11,311 INFO  plugin.PluginRepository -     Nutch Indexing Filter (org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexingFilter)

2012-09-13 12:56:11,311 INFO  plugin.PluginRepository -     HTML Parse Filter (org.apache.nutch.parse.HtmlParseFilter)

2012-09-13 12:56:11,311 INFO  plugin.PluginRepository -     Nutch Content Parser (org.apache.nutch.parse.Parser)

2012-09-13 12:56:11,311 INFO  plugin.PluginRepository -     Nutch Scoring (org.apache.nutch.scoring.ScoringFilter)

2012-09-13 12:56:11,313 INFO  indexer.IndexingFilters - Adding org.apache.nutch.indexer.basic.BasicIndexingFilter


2012-09-13 12:56:11,314 INFO  anchor.AnchorIndexingFilter - Anchor deduplication is: off

2012-09-13 12:56:11,314 INFO  indexer.IndexingFilters - Adding org.apache.nutch.indexer.anchor.AnchorIndexingFilter

2012-09-13 12:56:14,104 INFO  indexer.IndexingFilters - Adding org.apache.nutch.indexer.basic.BasicIndexingFilter

2012-09-13 12:56:14,104 INFO  anchor.AnchorIndexingFilter - Anchor deduplication is: off

2012-09-13 12:56:14,104 INFO  indexer.IndexingFilters - Adding org.apache.nutch.indexer.anchor.AnchorIndexingFilter

2012-09-13 12:56:17,135 INFO  indexer.IndexingFilters - Adding org.apache.nutch.indexer.basic.BasicIndexingFilter

2012-09-13 12:56:17,136 INFO  anchor.AnchorIndexingFilter - Anchor deduplication is: off

2012-09-13 12:56:17,136 INFO  indexer.IndexingFilters - Adding org.apache.nutch.indexer.anchor.AnchorIndexingFilter

2012-09-13 12:56:20,204 INFO  indexer.IndexingFilters - Adding org.apache.nutch.indexer.basic.BasicIndexingFilter

2012-09-13 12:56:20,205 INFO  anchor.AnchorIndexingFilter - Anchor deduplication is: off

2012-09-13 12:56:20,205 INFO  indexer.IndexingFilters - Adding org.apache.nutch.indexer.anchor.AnchorIndexingFilter

2012-09-13 12:56:23,297 INFO  indexer.IndexingFilters - Adding org.apache.nutch.indexer.basic.BasicIndexingFilter

2012-09-13 12:56:23,297 INFO  anchor.AnchorIndexingFilter - Anchor deduplication is: off

2012-09-13 12:56:23,297 INFO  indexer.IndexingFilters - Adding org.apache.nutch.indexer.anchor.AnchorIndexingFilter

2012-09-13 12:56:26,232 INFO  indexer.IndexingFilters - Adding org.apache.nutch.indexer.basic.BasicIndexingFilter

2012-09-13 12:56:26,232 INFO  anchor.AnchorIndexingFilter - Anchor deduplication is: off

2012-09-13 12:56:26,233 INFO  indexer.IndexingFilters - Adding org.apache.nutch.indexer.anchor.AnchorIndexingFilter

2012-09-13 12:56:29,252 INFO  indexer.IndexingFilters - Adding org.apache.nutch.indexer.basic.BasicIndexingFilter

2012-09-13 12:56:29,252 INFO  anchor.AnchorIndexingFilter - Anchor deduplication is: off

2012-09-13 12:56:29,252 INFO  indexer.IndexingFilters - Adding org.apache.nutch.indexer.anchor.AnchorIndexingFilter

2012-09-13 12:56:32,284 INFO  indexer.IndexingFilters - Adding org.apache.nutch.indexer.basic.BasicIndexingFilter

2012-09-13 12:56:32,284 INFO  anchor.AnchorIndexingFilter - Anchor deduplication is: off

2012-09-13 12:56:32,284 INFO  indexer.IndexingFilters - Adding org.apache.nutch.indexer.anchor.AnchorIndexingFilter

2012-09-13 12:56:35,258 INFO  indexer.IndexingFilters - Adding org.apache.nutch.indexer.basic.BasicIndexingFilter

2012-09-13 12:56:35,258 INFO  anchor.AnchorIndexingFilter - Anchor deduplication is: off

2012-09-13 12:56:35,258 INFO  indexer.IndexingFilters - Adding org.apache.nutch.indexer.anchor.AnchorIndexingFilter

2012-09-13 12:56:38,283 INFO  indexer.IndexingFilters - Adding org.apache.nutch.indexer.basic.BasicIndexingFilter

2012-09-13 12:56:38,284 INFO  anchor.AnchorIndexingFilter - Anchor deduplication is: off

2012-09-13 12:56:38,284 INFO  indexer.IndexingFilters - Adding org.apache.nutch.indexer.anchor.AnchorIndexingFilter

2012-09-13 12:56:41,278 INFO  indexer.IndexingFilters - Adding org.apache.nutch.indexer.basic.BasicIndexingFilter

2012-09-13 12:56:41,278 INFO  anchor.AnchorIndexingFilter - Anchor deduplication is: off

2012-09-13 12:56:41,278 INFO  indexer.IndexingFilters - Adding org.apache.nutch.indexer.anchor.AnchorIndexingFilter

2012-09-13 12:56:44,334 INFO  indexer.IndexingFilters - Adding org.apache.nutch.indexer.basic.BasicIndexingFilter

2012-09-13 12:56:44,334 INFO  anchor.AnchorIndexingFilter - Anchor deduplication is: off

2012-09-13 12:56:44,334 INFO  indexer.IndexingFilters - Adding org.apache.nutch.indexer.anchor.AnchorIndexingFilter

2012-09-13 12:56:47,338 INFO  indexer.IndexingFilters - Adding org.apache.nutch.indexer.basic.BasicIndexingFilter

2012-09-13 12:56:47,338 INFO  anchor.AnchorIndexingFilter - Anchor deduplication is: off

2012-09-13 12:56:47,338 INFO  indexer.IndexingFilters - Adding org.apache.nutch.indexer.anchor.AnchorIndexingFilter

2012-09-13 12:56:50,360 INFO  indexer.IndexingFilters - Adding org.apache.nutch.indexer.basic.BasicIndexingFilter

2012-09-13 12:56:50,360 INFO  anchor.AnchorIndexingFilter - Anchor deduplication is: off

2012-09-13 12:56:50,360 INFO  indexer.IndexingFilters - Adding org.apache.nutch.indexer.anchor.AnchorIndexingFilter

2012-09-13 12:56:53,309 INFO  indexer.IndexingFilters - Adding org.apache.nutch.indexer.basic.BasicIndexingFilter

2012-09-13 12:56:53,310 INFO  anchor.AnchorIndexingFilter - Anchor deduplication is: off

2012-09-13 12:56:53,310 INFO  indexer.IndexingFilters - Adding org.apache.nutch.indexer.anchor.AnchorIndexingFilter

2012-09-13 12:56:53,357 INFO  solr.SolrMappingReader - source: content dest: content

2012-09-13 12:56:53,357 INFO  solr.SolrMappingReader - source: title dest: title

2012-09-13 12:56:53,357 INFO  solr.SolrMappingReader - source: host dest: host

2012-09-13 12:56:53,357 INFO  solr.SolrMappingReader - source: segment dest: segment

2012-09-13 12:56:53,357 INFO  solr.SolrMappingReader - source: boost dest: boost

2012-09-13 12:56:53,357 INFO  solr.SolrMappingReader - source: digest dest: digest

2012-09-13 12:56:53,357 INFO  solr.SolrMappingReader - source: tstamp dest: tstamp

2012-09-13 12:56:53,357 INFO  solr.SolrMappingReader - source: url dest: id

2012-09-13 12:56:53,357 INFO  solr.SolrMappingReader - source: url dest: url

2012-09-13 12:56:53,409 INFO  solr.SolrWriter - Indexing 18 documents

2012-09-13 12:56:53,604 WARN  mapred.LocalJobRunner - job_local_0001

org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Missing solr core name in path

Missing solr core name in path

request: http://<host name>:8983/solr/update?wt=javabin&version=2
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.CommonsHttpSolrServer.request(CommonsHttpSolrServer.java:430)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.CommonsHttpSolrServer.request(CommonsHttpSolrServer.java:244)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.request.AbstractUpdateRequest.process(AbstractUpdateRequest.java:105)
    at org.apache.nutch.indexer.solr.SolrWriter.close(SolrWriter.java:142)
    at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexerOutputFormat$1.close(IndexerOutputFormat.java:48)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask$OldTrackingRecordWriter.close(ReduceTask.java:466)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runOldReducer(ReduceTask.java:530)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:420)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:260)
2012-09-13 12:56:53,981 ERROR solr.SolrIndexer - java.io.IOException: Job failed!
```

And in Solr i do not find any log file.

Please help me to sort out the problem i am really stuck with this.

Comment: You need to look at the Solr log file, which contains the detail of the error. Probably some required field is missing.

Comment: Could you add the Solr output so that we can help you?

Answer (score 2):

Your log says what the problem is:
`Missing solr core name in path`

Your request should have a name of Solr core between `/solr/` and `/update?wt=...`

Something like this: 
`http://<host name>:8983/solr/<core_name>/update?wt=javabin&version=2`

Perhaps you should add core name into your nutch command URL